# My jQuery code is not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer-7

My jQuery code is not working in IE7.

It's working in IE8, higher and all the rest of browsers.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#ListingPriceFormatted").bind('input propertychange', function () {
       $("#listingprice").val($("#ListingPriceFormatted").val().replace("$", "").replace(",", ""));
       $("#ListingPriceFormatted").val(formatCurrency($("#ListingPriceFormatted").val(), false));
    });
});


function formatCurrency(num, showCents) {
    num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
    if (isNaN(num)) num = "0";
    sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
    num = Math.floor(num * 100 + 0.50000000001);
    cents = num % 100;
    num = Math.floor(num / 100).toString();
    if (cents < 10) cents = "0" + cents;
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length - (1 + i)) / 3) ; i++)
        num = num.substring(0, num.length - (4 * i + 3)) + ',' + num.substring(num.length - (4 * i + 3));
    if (showCents) {
        return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + '$' + num + '.' + cents);
    }
    else {
        return (((sign) ? '' : '-') + '$' + num);
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Uncheck "disable script debugging" etc and post the full error message you get, otherwise we're in the dark here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `var` to declare all variables, IE7 has problems if this is missing.

```
var sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));

var cents = num % 100;
```

Comment: i got some error here 
  $("#listingprice").val($("#ListingPriceFormatted").val().replace("$", "").replace(",", ""));

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: $("#listingprice").val($("#ListingPriceFormatted").val().replace("$", "").replace(",", ""));


Object doesn't support this property or method